# Running apache on offline system

Tags: apache-httpd, libraries, dynamic-linking

I want to install apache using yum on CentOS 7 and check its shared libraries with `ldd` and pack the binary and files in apache's rpm and those libraries with full paths and transfer them to offline machine ,extract the files and run apache, I'm not sure what it will work, Do you think it is the correct approach and if not, What is your suggestion? I want to mention that I want only necessary files to run apache also the destination machine doesn't have exactly the same kernel, only major and minor version are the same (3.10.x)